# Unity does not launch in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, launcher

I updated from 13.10 from 14.04 a few weeks ago, and it was working fine.
But last night, after a login the wallpaper shows up, but the Unity does not,
and nothing else.
The weird thing is, that if I login as a Guest, it works 100%.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/76951#76951) didn't solve my issue, and it's for Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: this didn't solved my issue, and it's for ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Possible dupe of [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to rename all directories containing configuration files and cache in your home directory - they should be newly generated after logging in again. I am quite sure that this will work, but ALL YOUR SETTINGS WILL BE LOST.

First, switch to the command line interface using `ctrl+alt+F1` and log in.

Then rename all directories containing configuration files (do NOT delete them, just in case) using the following commands

```
mv .config .config_old
mv .cache .cache_old
mv .gconf .gconf.old
```

After having done this you have to log out and back in. As this is not possible using the GUI you can run the following command:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

This will restart the Xserver and you should be able to login. Unity should now work again, but all your settings are reset to their default values.

Comment: I WANT TO GIVE YOU A KISS!

Comment: I can't upvote you, I dont have 15 points :(

Comment: I am glad I could help :D