# launcher icons cannot be changed

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I deleted something in a cache folder and since then I cannot move or delete icons from the launcher bar. I did a reset of the icons, reinstalled desktop and unity, the whole system (didn't touch `/home`) could someone help me? I have Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You really need to find out what you deleted befor anyone can help

Comment: Does everything work as expected when you log in as guest?

Comment: Hi, as I remember, it was a folder named Cache.

Comment: Hi Kai, if I login as guest everything's ok.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late answer, you could try my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/463822/unity-does-not-launch-in-ubuntu-14-04/463847#463847

Comment: Hi, I tried you answer, but the problem persists. I can not move the icons, because if I release the left mouse button the cursor does not release the icon I just moved, I have to use esc to release it, than the icon goes back to it's original place. Maybe it looks now a different problem?

Comment: This is really weird since your account should now be nearly identical to the guest account. I have one last Idea: what happens when you rename the `.compiz`-Folder to e.g. `.compiz.old` and then log out and back in? (If that still won't work you could simply create another admin account and use that one instead and transfer all your personal files there)

Comment: Hi, nothing changed, I still can't release the grabbed icon on the launcher, nor remove it. I hope is there a more elegant solution, than creating an other admin account.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved by deleting the `~/.local/share/zeitgeist` folder and then restart.